# How to get date page was last modified using php?

Tags: php

I am using a php include function to include footer.html on every page on my site. In the footer I would like to have the date and time the page was last updated. How would I do this? So far the closest thing I found was filemtime() .

The file that displays the page is called index.php (i.e www.example.com/gallery/index.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`getlastmod()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getlastmod.php)

```
echo "Last modified: " . date ("F d Y H:i:s.", getlastmod());
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand the question. This depends quite a bit on your scenario.

For instance, if you're wanting to know when the last time the actual PHP script was edited, you'd need to use [`filemtime( $filename )`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) or [`getlastmod()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getlastmod.php).

However, this would not be accurate for content that is loaded dynamically. For a page showing discussion forums posts, it might be more accurate to show the last time content on the page has changed. (e.g., date of last post, date of last edit, etc...). This would depend on the content that you are including and displaying on the page, and when *it* was last updated. Not necessarily when the actual PHP script file was created or modified.

Comment: Eek! Thanks, hahaha. Oops.